# Hibernate - Sum two columns

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

everyone!

I'm trying to avoid to write the SQL/HQL query directly using Criteria, so I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this:

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Column
   private int a1;

   @Column
   private int a2;
   .....
}
```

What I want to do:

```
select sum(a1 + a2) from A
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, this can be done using `Formula` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Column(name ="a1")
   private int a1;

   @Column(name ="a2")
   private int a2;

   @Formula("a1 + a2")
   private int a3;
   .....
}
```

And in the Criteria:

```
Criteria cr = getInstanciaCriteria(A.class); 
cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projection‌​s.sum("a3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from Hibernate's docs:

> HQL queries can even return the results of aggregate functions on
>   properties:
>
> select avg(cat.weight), sum(cat.weight), max(cat.weight), count(cat)
>   from Cat cat
>
> The supported aggregate functions are:
>
> ```
> avg(...), sum(...), min(...), max(...)
>
> count(*)
> ```

so `SELECT sum(e.a1+e.a2) FROM Entity e` should be fine.

Comment: `Criteria cr = getInstanciaCriteria(A.class);

cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.sum("a1 + a2"));` I was trying to do this, but I know it's wrong.

Comment: Ìt doesn't recognize the column `a1 + a2`

Comment: Did you try root.get("a1"),root.get("a2") ??